# Access a variable from another

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on a simple MFC program, that consist of three classes (generated automatically by the Visual Studio wizard):

- A `CWinApp` derivative, `MyWinApp`
- A `CDocument`derivative, `MyDocument`
- A `CView` derivative, `MyView`
- A `CFrameWnd` derivative called `CMainFrame`

and finally a dialogue box class, derived from `CDialog` named

- `MyDialog`

`MyDialog` has an edit box that allows the user to input an integer value. After clicking `OK` I'd like that value (let's call it `s_value`) to be used in a drawing algorithm inside the function `MyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC){...}`

For example, the `OnDraw()` function looks something like:

```
{...
SetPixel(posX, posY, (s_value < 5) ? color1 : color2);
... }
```

However I can't figure out how to get the variable representing the value in the edit box, located inside the `MyDialog` class into the drawing formula inside the `OnDraw` function in the `MyView` class.

For example, if I want to call the methods in `MyView` from `MyDialog`, I have to create new objects and everything is getting messed up. I'm having similar problems with static variables.

Please note, I come from a Java background so my C++ is a little fuzzy. I apologize in advance if this isn't such a sophisticated question.

Answer (score 2):

> if I want to call the methods in MyView from MyDialog

You typically do not want to do that.  With your description, your dialog has a value you want to use in your view (somewhere).  Using the standard MFC paradigm (which is very similar to other Model-View-Controller paradigms), you want to store the value of the edit box (that is on your dialog) as a variable in your document.  Then, when your view is drawing, it pulls the data from your document to render it.  It would look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
// in your document declaration
public:
    CString m_StringDataMember; // NOTE:  you may want to create accessors instead of public members - this is shown this way for simplicity.

// somewhere in your view
MyDialog dlg;
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    ((MyDocument*)GetDocument())->m_StringDataMember = dlg.m_EditBoxValue; // assuming you created the edit box and had it map to a CString variable already
    Invalidate();
}

// In your OnDraw or OnUpdate function
MyDocument* pDlg = ((MyDocument*)GetDocument());
// Do something with pDlg->m_StringDataMember
```

The process is similar if you wanted to use an integer value (though, you probably would want to set up minimum and maximum values and use a spinner control in your dialog as well).

Comment: +1 This is a common way to do it. Another MFC Doc/View "way" would be to have the App itself act as the idealistic MVC controller, set the member in the model (i.e. the Doc), and invalidate the view as is done here.

Comment: Why do I need `m_StringDataMember`?

Comment: @Imray You need the value stored *somewhere*.  The document (in MFC) is where you typically store your data and your view is where you display it (the idea being that you can potentially have multiple views of the same data - in fact, may non-trivial MFC applications make use of that fact extensively).

Answer (score 0):

Is the dialog modal or modeless? If it's modal use Zac Howland's suggestion of waiting until dlg.DoModal() returns and then store the integer value in the document or directly in your view class. If it's modeless then you will have to pass a pointer to either the document or view object into your dialog constructor. Then write a handler for EN_CHANGE notification and call a view or document method to update the value. Maybe something like:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog( MyDocument* pDoc, CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(MyDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , m_pDoc(pDoc)
{
}

ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_SVALUE, &MyDialog::OnEnChangeSValue)

void MyDialog::OnEnChangeSValue()
{
    m_pDoc->SetSValue( GetDlgItemInt( IDC_SVALUE ));
}


void MyDocument::SetSValue( int svalue )
{
    m_svalue = svalue;
    UpdateAllViews( NULL, HINT_SVALUE );
}

void MyView::OnUpdate( CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint )
{
    if( lHint == HINT_SVALUE ) do something
}
```